How to prevent the 'figure' window from popping up when calling axes()
I have a function for creating subplot positions. However, When I call this function, the line "axes(ha(i))" always causes the figure window to pop up. How can I modify this line to prevent the figure window from popping up? Thanks!
fig = figure('visible','off')
ha = tight_subplot(1, 2, [0.02, 0.02], [0.05, 0.05], [0.05, 0.05]);
for i = 1:numel(ha)
   
      axes(ha(i));
     plot([3:4]); hold on
end


function ha = tight_subplot(Nh, Nw, gap, marg_h, marg_w)

% tight_subplot creates "subplot" axes with adjustable gaps and margins
%
% ha = tight_subplot(Nh, Nw, gap, marg_h, marg_w)
%
%   in:  Nh      number of axes in hight (vertical direction)
%        Nw      number of axes in width (horizontaldirection)
%        gap     gaps between the axes in normalized units (0...1)
%                   or [gap_h gap_w] for different gaps in height and width 
%        marg_h  margins in height in normalized units (0...1)
%                   or [lower upper] for different lower and upper margins 
%        marg_w  margins in width in normalized units (0...1)
%                   or [left right] for different left and right margins 
%
%  out:  ha     array of handles of the axes objects
%                   starting from upper left corner, going row-wise as in
%                   going row-wise as in
%
%  Example: ha = tight_subplot(3,2,[.01 .03],[.1 .01],[.01 .01])
%           for ii = 1:6; axes(ha(ii)); plot(randn(10,ii)); end
%           set(ha(1:4),'XTickLabel',''); set(ha,'YTickLabel','')

% Pekka Kumpulainen 20.6.2010   @tut.fi
% Tampere University of Technology / Automation Science and Engineering


if nargin<3; gap = .02; end
if nargin<4 || isempty(marg_h); marg_h = .05; end
if nargin<5; marg_w = .05; end

if numel(gap)==1; 
    gap = [gap gap];
end
if numel(marg_w)==1; 
    marg_w = [marg_w marg_w];
end
if numel(marg_h)==1; 
    marg_h = [marg_h marg_h];
end

axh = (1-sum(marg_h)-(Nh-1)*gap(1))/Nh; 
axw = (1-sum(marg_w)-(Nw-1)*gap(2))/Nw;

py = 1-marg_h(2)-axh; 


ha = zeros(Nh*Nw,1);
ii = 0;
for ih = 1:Nh
    px = marg_w(1);
    
    for ix = 1:Nw
        ii = ii+1;
        ha(ii) = axes('Units','normalized', ...
            'Position',[px py axw axh], ...
            'XTickLabel','', ...
            'YTickLabel','');
        px = px+axw+gap(2);
    end
    py = py-axh-gap(1);
end


You can set the current active axes with
fig.CurrentAxes = ha(i);

This way the figure window will stay in the background.

I'm assuming you are using the axes line to direct the subsequent plot to those axes. For that, you can simply pass the axes as a first argument to plot. So, instead of

axes(ha(i)); 
plot([3:4]); hold on

use
plot(ha(i), [3:4]); hold on


Thank you, that's also a good idea. However, I want to find a more concise way to set image parameters without needing to add ha(i) to every line of code, like title(ha(i), ...).
